# Where to put user related get functions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a problem I am working on for quite a while now.

I am using Laravel 5.0 and have relationships set up:

- A user can have many itineraries
- A itinerary can have many destinations
- A user has many destinations through itineraries

Now I am trying to set up a function which I need in many controllers. I have this function in User.php:

```
public function last_destination() {
    return $last_destination =
        \App\Destination::where('itinerary_id', auth()->user()->active_itinerary_id)
        ->orderBy('order_index', 'DESC')
        ->first();
}
```

When I try to retrieve the last destination, it works fine, but when I pass the last destination as a variable to a view, it throughs me the error: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Should I put this function in another class? If so where should I put it to still be able to call it as $user->last_destination()?

I appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian

Comment: Can you show the code you used to display the `last_destination` in your view?

Comment: In my controller I have: 
`$last_destination = auth()->user()->last_destination();
return view('destinanations.create')->with('last_destination', $last_destination');`

And in my view I call e.g. `{{ $last_destination['city'] }}`

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely trying to call `$user->last_destination` somewhere, as you would if that method returned a `Relation`.

Try using `$user->last_destination()` instead. Or updating your method to return a `Relation` instance.

Comment: No, I am calling $user->last_destination() but still receive this error. I am returning a single model and not a collection. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other place where you call it as an attribute instead of as method? Where is the exception thrown? (File and line). Is it the controller or the view?

Comment: I agree with @Alejandro. To my knowledge, the only way to encounter that error is if you are trying to access that method as a property. Maybe try doing a search in your project for "->last_destination", see what comes up.